# How to add data plot to existing graphs in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, figure

I have a plot that I've made using `subplot2grid()` - I now want to overlay another figure on top [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryqE0.png).  I thought I could do this by plotting a big plot to cover the existing (using `subplot2grid(111)`) figure & making the background & axes invisible but this doesn't work.

Edit: my issue is because I have a grid of subplots, and I now need to overlay over the whole figure - but it is broken down into subplots.

My existing code is something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
ax1.plot(x1, y1)

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,1), rowspan=1, colspan=1))
ax2.plot(x2, y2)

plt.show()
```

and I have tried:

```
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
**
ax3.plot(x3, y3)
```

where ** is the various methods I have tried to make the plot transparent.

Thank you

Comment: Use ```gridspec```, more specifically, does this answer your question? [Embedding multiple gridspec layouts on a single matplotlib figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933233/embedding-multiple-gridspec-layouts-on-a-single-matplotlib-figure)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, it would be helpful if you showed more code, but generally, to have two plots overlay in python you would call the plt.plot function twice, and then use plt.show() to display both.

It would look like this(this is just an example) :

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

X1 = [1, 2, 3, 5 ,6]
X2 = [4, 5, 3, 1, 7]
Y = np.arange(0, 1, 6)

plt.plot(X1,Y)
plt.plot(X2,Y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry it wasn't very clear - I've edited now, hopefully it makes more sense.  My issue is that I need to plot another set of axes of different dimensions to the existing axes, on top of the existing axes - & still be able to see the other data underneath.

Comment: I'm also confused, so why do you need to have the subplots?